# C++ function name demangling: What does this name suffix mean?

Tags: c++, assembly, g++, chromium

When I disassemble the Chromium binary I notice there are functions named in this pattern: 
`_ZN6webrtc15DecoderDatabase11DecoderInfoD2Ev.part.1`

If I give this string to c++filt, the output is
`webrtc::DecoderDatabase::DecoderInfo::~DecoderInfo() [clone .part.1]`

So what does this .part.1 suffix really mean? If it indicates there are multiple copies of the same function, why do they need that? Is it due to the requirement of being position independent? I used g++ as the compiler.

Comment: Functions may be overloaded with different parameter signatures.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: destructors too?

Comment: I'm only guessing, but I would bet this is an optimization. Rather than emitting the same block of code in several functions, it emits one common block of code and several stubs that call it. This is particularly likely with destructors, which could be called in several ways (subclass versus via `delete`, for example.)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm aware of that. In that case, functions have different mangled names. But this does not explain the ".part.1" thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It indicates that destructor was the target of a [partial inlining optimization](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2014/10/29/rhel7-gcc-optimizations-partial-inlining/) by GCC. With this optimization the function is only partially inlined into another function, the remainder gets emitted into its own partial function. Since this new partial function doesn't implement the complete function it's given a different name, so it can exist beside a definition of the complete function if necessary.

So for example it appears that [DecoderDatabase::DecoderInfo::~DecoderInfo](https://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3425/trunk/webrtc/modules/audio_coding/neteq4/decoder_database.cc) is defined like this:

```
DecoderDatabase::DecoderInfo::~DecoderInfo() {
    if (!external) delete decoder;
}
```

My guess is that `delete decoder` invokes a long series of operations, too long to be inlined into another function. The optimizer would accordingly split those operations into a partial function. It would then only inline the `if (!external)` part of the function into other functions.

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't heard of partial inlining before.