# filename_lookup.part.64 vs filename_lookup symbols

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, system-calls, kernel-module

We have a kernel module using filename_lookup call which is not exported anymore in RHEL8 Kernel 4.18. But found another system call exported in /proc/kallsyms, which is **filename_lookup.part.64**

What is **filename_lookup.part.64** ? Can I call it in our code using the address exported in /proc/kallsyms?

I am not able to find any documentation on filename_lookup.part.64.

Is it safe to use this kind of undocumented APIs?

```
struct filename filename = { .name = name };
struct nameidata nd;
filename_lookup(AT_FDCWD, &filename, LOOKUP_PARENT, &nd);
```

I am looking to find the calls that can be used to replace the above in the absence of filename_lookup()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ function name demangling: What does this name suffix mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683913/c-function-name-demangling-what-does-this-name-suffix-mean)

Comment: No C function can have a dot (`.`) in its name: this violates the C syntax. Only a compiler may add "forbidden" characters to the name of the symbols. Obviously, such symbols cannot be documented - they are part of the compiling process, not a part of the code.

Comment: I cannot find any evidence that `filename_lookup` has ever been exported to modules.

Comment: I just tried RHEL 7.3 with 3.10.0-514.el7 and filename_lookup is found kallsyms.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question

> What is filename_lookup.part.64 ? Can I call it in our code using the
> address exported in /proc/kallsyms?

as can be read at [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223013/function-symbol-gets-part-suffix-after-compilation), it is the original filename_lookup function without some parts that the compiler optimized and set them inline, so its not safe.

As said earlier [@user3248278](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3248278/user3248278), would be easier to use the wrappers such as [kern_path](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/namei.c#L2541) or [user_path_at_empty](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/namei.c#L2734).

Answer (score 0):

Filename_lookup is now wrapped with various APIs, which are exported, for example -
*int **kern_path**(const char *name, unsigned int flags, struct path *path)* - for getting inodes in kernels.
You can easily search in elixir for *filename_lookup* and you can find the wrappers.